# Registration button enabled only if mail is correct

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

I have a form for registration with **Username**, **Email**, **Password** and **Password confirm** with a disabled Submit button. I would like to enable the button only if the email is correct. In my case I allow only email with "@studio.unibo.it" and not other email domains (the prefix email control is done in Javascript). And if a user change, after that the button in enabled, the email, the button must be again disabled. So, only if the user insert an e-mail like peter@studio.unibo.it can be registered.
I already have "required" key in each form fields.

It is possible to do this in javascript or with a php control?

Here is the code:
**HTML Form**:

```
<form action="registration.php" method="post" id="fileForm" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">     
        <label for="firstname"> Username: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Input_Username" id = "txt" onkeyup = "Validate(this)" placeholder="Username" required /> 
        <div id="errFirst"></div>    
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email"> Email: </label> 
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Input_Email" id = "email"  onchange="email_validate(this.value);" placeholder="nome.cognomeX@studio.unibo.it" required />   
        <div class="status" id="status"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password"> Password: </label>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control inputpass" minlength="4" maxlength="16"  id="pass1" placeholder="Password" required /> </p>

        <label for="password"> Password Confirm: </label>
        <input name="Input_Password" type="password" class="form-control inputpass" minlength="4" maxlength="16" placeholder="Enter again to validate"  id="pass2" onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;" required />
        <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled>Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">Reset</button>
    </div>       
</form><!-- ends register form -->
```

**Javascript script** for password check and email prefix check

```
 function checkPass()
    {
        //Store the password field objects into variables ...
        var pass1 = document.getElementById('pass1');
        var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass2');
        //Store the Confimation Message Object ...
        var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');

        var goodColor = "#66cc66";
        var badColor = "#ff6666";

        if(pass1.value == pass2.value){

            pass2.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
            message.style.color = goodColor;
            message.innerHTML = "Le password combaciano"
        }else{
            pass2.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
            message.style.color = badColor;
            message.innerHTML = "Le password non combaciano"
        }
    } 

    // validates text only
    function Validate(txt) {
        txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z-'\n\r.]+/g, '');
    }
    // validate email
    function email_validate(email)
    {
    var regMail = /^([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@(studio.unibo.it)$/; //ammesse solo le mail che terminano per @studio.unibo.it !!!

        if(regMail.test(email) == false)
        {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML    = "<span class='warning'>L'indirizzo email non è valido.</span>";
        }
        else
        {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<span class='valid'>L'indirizzo email è valido.</span>"; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can definitely do this in js. However, you should also validate it in PHP when the form is posted. (never trust js-validation since it's run in the users browser and can be manipulated). I see that you already have some validation for it? Does it work or what error are you getting?

Comment: I don't know how to enable my Submit button if the email is correct. I don't have errors, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Give the submit button an id, like `id="submit-btn"` and then simply do: `document.getElementById('submit-btn').disabled = false;` to enable it.

Comment: it's good but is this way if the user modify the email after that the button is enabled, the button stay enabled and the user can registry also if a wrong email. I would like that the button turn disabled if the email it's modified by the user.

Comment: You have "onchange" so if the validation fails, just set `document.getElementById('submit-btn').disabled = true` again.

Comment: right! thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

```
var email = ...; //get your email input
var submit = ...;//get your submit button
email.onchange = function() {
    submit.disabled = !validate(email.value); //validate - your function validates email address
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.